# Navigate to Event Handler Does not work in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, ide, event-handling

I am studying a code base developed using .NET WPF. I am using Visual Studio 2008 IDE. In the XAML code, I have a line as follows:

```
<MenuItem Header="About"  Click="Main_Window_ContextMenu_About_Click">
```

Clicking right mouse button, I see a option called "Navigate to Event Handler". However, clicking it does not take me to the Event Handler definition. In fact, this action seems to have no effect.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953196) is a known issue. There are several ways to fix it, including re installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ReSharper, hit F12 while the cursor is on the event handler name (assuming you're using ReSharper's default shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

That shortcut in the XAML designer isn't very reliable - it only works when the event handler method is defined in the code-behind for the XAML file. For example, if you have "Window.xaml" it will only work if the handler is in "Window.xaml.cs".

This breaks, for example, if the event handler is defined in a second partial class file like "Window_EventHandlers.cs". This particular one even generates a new blank event handler in the code-behind file which promptly fails to compile on a duplicate method definition - yuck!

If you can't find it, your best bet is probably a solution or project-wide search for the method name.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but not sure if this is the case with me. I have created a very simple WPF App. The event handler is defined in the respetice cs file. I am still not able to navigate.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. It generally also doesn't work when the program won't compile, or at least specifically when the designer is objecting to the XAML containing the event handler. That's nothing a recompile or a VS restart wouldn't fix though. - Also are ALL event handlers breaking or just the one?

Comment: There was just on in that example. But in a separate project, all of them were breaking.